# Showing a busy indicator or a loading image while loading large QML file

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on a QML based app. where I dynamically load the content. However when running the application it takes quite a long time (5-10 secs), so I need to show any loading screen or indicator while the whole content is being loaded. Can anyone suggest me how to do it ?
For example, after I login in my application it took some time to load the next page so within that oeriod of time i want to show the loading screen.

```
App {
id: app
height: 400
width: 200
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle       
        Button {
            id: button
            text: qsTr("GO TO NEXT PAGE")
            onClicked:stackView.push("page2.qml")                
        }        
        Image {
            id: image
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "default-app.png"
        }
    }
```

}
Suppose this is my code then where can i use loader ? I never used it before

Comment: pardon me, but where is the mentioned `StackView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `status` from a `Loader` component (I'm guessing you are using that since you are loading "dynamically"). Then use that in a `BusyIndicator`.

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    asynchronous: true
    ...

    BusyIndicator {
         anchors.centerIn: parent
         running: loader.status == Loader.Loading 
    }
}
```

Heck, the [Qt docs for BusyIndicator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-busyindicator.html) should have get you going!

Comment: Ohne should also set  `asynchronous: true`

Comment: I have not used loader. for redirect to next page i use stackView

Comment: @user13846567 that goes to show you should include code in your question! And then you should start using a `Loader` in your `StackView`